# Magento2.3- Inventory Management unable to decrease Salable Quantity

Tags: magento2, inventory, quantity, salable, decrements

I am using Magento2.3.2 version.

Example:

1)I added `one` product with `5` Quantity.

So, Quantity is now `5` and Salable Quantity also `5`.

2)Now I realize I have only `4` quantity and by mistake, I added `5`.

So, I update the Quantity from `5` to `4`.

So now Quantity is `4` and salable quantity is `5`.

How to `decrease Salable Quantity`?

Another Example:

1)Create a new product with `1` quantity.

So, Quantity is `1` and Salable quantity is `1`.

2)Now that product is sold offline.

So, I edit the product and set Quantity to `0`.

So now the Quantity is `0` but the Salable Quantity is `1`.

How to decrease `Salable Quantity`?

Any trick from admin or any module for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain you here how saleable quantity logic was worked in M2, but read below link it the best example of how saleable quantity mechanism works.

*[Magento2 - Salable Quantity Calculation and Mechanism of Reservations](https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations)*

If you still have any confusion let me know i will give you more idea about saleable quantity.

Comment: I know how it works. but my question is how to decrease salable quantity without placing order.